# Writing a book review

Tags: fiction, novel, book, reviews, reviewing

I just came across a question that related to the topic of book reviews.

I wish to know, how can I start as a reviewer and where can I find sample reviews of some non-technical books or novels?

In this case do I need to directly contact the publisher or is there is any other means for doing that?

Answer (score 3):

**Publishers tend to look to other authors** for book reviews, because they can add statements from these authors that give the promoted book weight.

You can look at blogs, Amazon and Goodreads for samples of reviews.

A lot of **book reviewers start their own blogs/websites** and authors seek them out for reviews once they have achieved a following. **A book reviewer with a large audience is classed as an influencer and can be heavily in demand.**

Reedsy, which is highly-regarded in the publishing community, has a list of bloggers who do reviews and you could look at their sites for inspiration:

[Best Book Review Blogs of 2019](https://blog.reedsy.com/book-review-blogs/)

**The secret is to get started.** Review on Amazon and Goodreads for practice, start your own review blog, and gather your audience.

One tip though: always try to see the good and the bad in things you review. **Don't look for fault or confuse criticism with critique**. Writing a book, even a bad one, is an extremely challenging and difficult task. And writers see their creations like their babies, thrust out into the world. So, think carefully before you bludgeon it with a brick.

**Writers remember reviewers who are unnecessarily harsh** and steer clear of them when looking for reviewers.

Good luck!

p.s. I have a book coming out later this year, you can review that if you like!

Comment: Sure, do let me know when the same is published. I will review it. \